# check if xml node exists with serialization in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a program running that reads serialized xml files.  These files come to me from a résumé parsing service.  Since these are résumés, there are a lot of nodes in the xml file that are not required so I need to check if they exist before trying to get the value of them.   The problem is I have been getting some Object reference errors on some of these.

Here is an example of some of the code that I currently have in place

```cs
        if (obj.HireAbilityXMLResults.Resume.StructuredXMLResume.References != null)
        {
            string ReferenceName = "";
            string ReferenceAddress = "";
            string ReferencePhone = "";
            string ReferenceRelation = "";
            string areaCode = "";
            string subscriberNumber = "";
            string refCity = "";
            string refState = "";

            var references = obj.HireAbilityXMLResults.Resume.StructuredXMLResume.References;
            foreach (var r in references)
            {
                ReferenceName = r.Reference.PersonName.FormattedName.ToString();
                if (r.Reference.ContactMethod != null)
                {
                    if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.Telephone != null)
                    {
                        if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.Telephone.AreaCityCode != null)
                        {
                            areaCode = r.Reference.ContactMethod.Telephone.AreaCityCode.ToString();
                        }
                        if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.Telephone.SubscriberNumber != null)
                        {
                            subscriberNumber = r.Reference.ContactMethod.Telephone.SubscriberNumber.ToString();
                        }
                        ReferencePhone = areaCode + "-" + subscriberNumber;
                    }
                    if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress != null)
                    {
                        if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Municipality != null)
                        {
                            refCity = r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Municipality.ToString();
                        }
                        if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region != null)
                        {
                            refState = r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region.ToString();
                        }
                        ReferenceAddress = refCity + "," + refState;
                    }
                }
                if (r.Reference.PositionTitle != null)
                {
                    ReferenceRelation = r.Reference.PositionTitle.ToString();
                }
                ProfessionalReferences proRefs = new ProfessionalReferences();
                proRefs.Add(UserID, ReferenceName.LimitLength(50), ReferencePhone, ReferenceAddress.LimitLength(50), ReferenceRelation.LimitLength(20), x);
                x++;
            }

        }
```

The problem I am having is if the node does not exist I am getting errors telling me that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

For sake of argument let's say someone lists John Smith Chicago as a possible reference but does not put in IL so this node will not exist  `r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region` and then this line would throw an error

```
if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region != null)
```

I read an answer where someone said to use is object instead like so

```
if (r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region is object)
```

Is this the proper way to make sure the node exists?

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: I believe I answered your question. Please do not forget to upvote and select a best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
if (r?.Reference?.ContactMethod?.PostalAddress?.Region != null)
```

This will propogate null values rather than throwing null reference exceptions.

As an aside, the large amounts of member access operators in a row (`r.Reference.ContactMethod.PostalAddress.Region`) is quite a code smell. It reeks of poorly designed data structures, [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) violations and violations of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

You will want to encapsulate the concepts of your code into methods. Ask yourself, "What am I trying to accomplish?" and make a method with that name. For example your code appears to be checking if the reference has valid contact information. So `Reference` should have a method called `HasValidContactInformation`:

```
class Reference
{
     public bool HasValidContactInformation()
     {
          //you write your implementation here
     }
}
```

If you ever find yourself more than 1 or 2 dots (field/property access operators) deep, you should consider encapsulating your logic into a method.

Comment: I would if your solution solved the issue.  However, even using the Null Conditional operator I still get Null Reference errors on the foreach line                                                                   `if(obj?.HireAbilityXMLResults?.Resume?.StructuredXMLResume?.ContactInfo?.ContactMethod != null)
{
   var contactMethod = obj.HireAbilityXMLResults.Resume.StructuredXMLResume.ContactInfo.ContactMethod;
   foreach (var cm in contactMethod)
   {
   }
}`

Comment: @Miranda You need to use the null-conditional operator on all of your long member access chains. like this: `obj?.HireAbilityXMLResults?.Resume?.StructuredXMLResume?.References`.

Comment: @Miranda and of course if `references` is null the foreach loop will throw an exception. So check that `references` is not null before you start the loop. The goal of my question was to explain the concept, not to rewrite your entire code for you

Comment: it isn't the references section throwing errors

Comment: @Miranda `var contactMethod = obj?.HireAbilityXMLResults?.Resume?.StructuredXMLResume?.ContactInfo?.ContactMethod;
                if(contactMethod!= null) {  foreach (var cm in contactMethod) { } }`

Comment: @Miranda if instead of writing long chains of `?.` operators you should just refactor your concepts into a method, as I described in my answer. This will make your problem apparent quickly. Also, step into  your code with the debugger and look at each of the variables to see which one is null

Comment: @Miranda as a rule of thumb you should never have more than one member access operator in a row. `obj.HireAbilityXMLResults` is ok, but `obj.HireAbilityXMLResults.Resume` is already a big red flag

Comment: Why doesn't the if statement right above there catch that it is null?    If it is null then shouldn't the if statement catch that, and then the code within that be skipped?

Comment: @Miranda STEP IN WITH A DEBUGGER. No one knows without stepping into the code. Hell, it could be that `contactMethod.GetEnumerator()` is returning null during the foreach loop. You have the tools to figure it out. Just set a breakpoint on the line where you are getting the error and examine the variable values

Comment: Because the errors were sporadic, only a few people were getting them,  I had the system send me email with a copy of a resume that threw an error.  I was then able to step through using the debugger on a resume that caused an error to see what the issue was.     Thanks for your help